# Prove that the sets $S$ and $D$ have the same cardinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Prove that the sets $S$ and $D$ have the same cardinality, where $S = \{(x,y)\mid-1\leq x \leq 1\text{ and }-1\leq y\leq 1\}$ and $D = \{(x,y)\mid x^2 + y^2 \leq 1\}$.

Comment: It's better if you tell us what you did; and what you know about these sets.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Define the map $f:[-1,1]^2\to D$ such that 
$$f(x,y) = \frac{\max\{|x|,|y|\}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}(x,y),       $$
then prove this map is one-to-one and onto!

Comment: what do you mean by max {|x|,|y|}?

Comment: maximum of $|x|$ and $|y|$!

Comment: @Pasie15 Is it clear?

Comment: so you plug in x= 1 and y=1 into the the sqrt(x^2 + y^2) right?

Comment: yes! just check some points you will see it works!

Comment: so would I get F(1,1) = sqrt(2) / sqrt(x^2 + y^2)?

Comment: hey mohammad you saw my last question?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** Both these sets are subsets of $\Bbb R^2$, whose cardinality is the same as that of $\Bbb R$. It suffices to find subsets of both these sets (or even a subset of $D\cap S$) whose cardinality is also the same as $\Bbb R$.